# JObject jo = new JObject() (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for some information about how to work with Azure Mobile Services, in a Windows Phone Client. As we can check at [this link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/work-with-net-client-library/?fb=us-en#deleting), there's some examples about how to work with mobile services.

In my case, I want to delete an ID from my SQL database. For this, we can use the example code from MSDN Documentation:

```
JObject jo = new JObject(); 
jo.Add("Id", "37BBF396-11F0-4B39-85C8-B319C729AF6D");
await table.DeleteAsync(jo);
```

When i paste this code into my function, I cant compile it because JObject.
This is the error I got at `JObject jo = new JObject();` line:

> The type or namespace name 'JObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just can't instance a new JObject object, but the `Newtonsoft.JSON` are referred in my project. So I think it should work fine, but I cant instance a JObject.

Comment: the reference to Newtonsoft.JSON may be "broken", can you post your whole solution?

Comment: Hello Igor, how can i post my solution here? I mean, what you want to do?

Comment: upload the solution somwhere and post a link

Answer (score 2):

This JObject class belongs to JSON.NET library (Newtonsoft).

Here's the full namespace:

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

If you can't compile, probably you don't have the JSON.NET library in your project. Add Newtonsoft library to your project using Nuget Package.

In your VS, open your solution, open the menu Tools -> Library package manager -> package manager console

PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

When working with Windows Azure Mobile Services and Windows Phone 8. I recommend on starting from downloading the template project right from Mobile Service dashboard.

If you want to use existing project then follow the guide from dashboard how to get started.